# How to rotate a list to the right?

Tags: prolog

My code just rotates to the left. How do I rotate right?

```
rotar(X,X,0).
rotar([CA|CO],L,X):-X1 is X-1, append(CO,[CA],CO1), rotar(CO1, L, X1).
```

Comment: I tried to do it as the code that you marked as a duplicate, but when doing the rotation X many times I do not understand how to do it. Any advice?